# BinaryFormatter outofmemory exception deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a [serializable] class that I serialize using a binary formatter, send over a network (TCPListener, TCPClient) and then run deserialize on. Every time I get to deserialize I get an outofmemory exception. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

(The class I'm sending is very small)

Thanks,

PM

EDIT: My class is a linked list of one of my other classes, and some methods. I made both Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class have a serialization constructor (one that takes the `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` params)? If so, might there be a bug in the serialization constructor?

(Please provide more details on the class in question.)

Comment: No, I just put a [Serializable] block above the class declaration the class doesn't actually implement ISerializable.

Comment: If you want to be certain about what is on the wire and what is not, try using [DataMemeber] attribute near every field, starting with single small field. And put more [DataMember] attributes until you hit the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the serializer and/or deserializer have trouble with cyclic references.

I'd recommend custom serializers & deserializers anyway. It really is beneficial to be able to look at just your code and know what the storage format looks like.